# Loopback mongodb-connector principalId stored as string

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback with the mongodb connector. When doing a query to find all roles assigned to a user the response returns nothing.

```
// Find all users
$scope.displayUsers = [];
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.users = User.find({
        include: ['roles']
}, function() {
    $scope.displayUsers.concat($scope.users);
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

I have narrowed it down to the principalId being stored as a string in the Rolemapping model while the userId is of type ObjectId. When I change the principalId type ObjectId manually in my database the query seems to work.

I have found a similar issue here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/676

I have tried to follow the suggestions but it does not seem to solve my problem. Has anyone found a solution to a similar issue?

Comment: depend on your project, perhaps you could just map the objectId value to string type? I did that in my project. `RoleMapping.find({where: {principalId: user.id.toString()}})`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported already in [issue #1441](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1441). Which I found a workaround for it:

```
RoleMapping.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(RoleMapping, {foreignKey: 'principalId'});
Role.hasMany(User, {through: RoleMapping, foreignKey: 'roleId'});

var ObjectID = RoleMapping.getDataSource().connector.getDefaultIdType();
RoleMapping.defineProperty('principalId', {
  type: ObjectID,
});
```